# C# converting values back to object from abstract class

Tags: c#

I need some help in the code below. I am trying to retrieve a value from inherited class.

```
public abstract class Amount
{        
}

public class Quantity : Amount
{
    public decimal quantityDecimal;

    public Quantity(decimal decimal_qty)
    {
        this.quantityDecimal= decimal_qty;
    }
}

public class Portion : Amount
{
    public decimal portionDecimal;

    public Portion (decimal decimal_qty)
    {
        this.portionDecimal= decimal_qty;
    }
}
```

And this is how i calculate amount from qty or por based on the logic

```
public Amount createAmount(Quantity qty, Portion por)
{
   //sample logic here
   Amount compQuantity = qty;
   Amount comPortion = por;

   Amount compAmount = compQuantity ?? comPortion;
}
```

And this is how i am trying to retrieve Amount value as a string, but i am unable to return the value. it just return Type of Amount class as a string. Any help on this please.

```
public string GetAmount(Amount amt)
{
   string return_str = amt.ToString(); //amt has the value but i can not assign it to return_str
   return 
}
```

Comment: Override the `ToString()` function in each of your classes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you are trying to retrieve when you say `Amount value`. Right now, your abstract class doesn't serve much purpose as you're just defining the value properties in your inherited classes. If both derived classes have decimal values, you should do something similar to what the answer below suggested and define a decimal `Value` property in the abstract class and then set it by calling the `base` constructor on your derived classes. Then, you can even override the `ToString()` method in your abstract class if you need a specific type of format.

Comment: Okay, it is because i am not a expert at C#. so the answer from @gsharp guided me right. Why this question is down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place Amount in the base class to achieve what you want. So that it's inherited to the concrete implementation Quantity/Portion.
(I wouldn't misuse `.ToString()` for that)

Here a small sample

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var q = new Quantity(15);
        Portion p = null;
        var amount = GetAmount(q, p);
    }

    private static decimal GetAmount(Quantity q, Portion p)
    {
        AmountBase a   = (AmountBase)q ?? p;

        return a.Amount;
    }
}


public abstract class AmountBase
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public AmountBase(decimal amount)
    {
        Amount = amount;
    }
}

public class Quantity : AmountBase
{
    public Quantity(decimal amount) : base(amount)
    {

    }
}

public class Portion : AmountBase
{
    public Portion(decimal amount) : base(amount)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i was actually looking for such solution.